# How to click the first clickable date on the datepicker calendar in selenium webdriver?

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver, webdriver

How to click the first click able date on the *datepicker* calendar? Below is the span block for the code. In this case, the first click able date was 28. What is the *xpath* that will allow me to click on 28

```
<span class="day ng-binding selected-day" data-ng-class="{'selected-day'  : isDateSelected(months[currentMonth], $index)}">28</span>
```

Comment: Can you paste the entire calendar block code? That would help in identifying what is unique with the first available date

Answer (score 1):

Get the xpath and replace the date. For example:

```
xpath = "//div[@id='ui-datepicker-div']/div[.//span[.='MONTH']]//table[@class='ui-datepicker-calendar']//a[.='DATE']";
xpath=xpath.replace("MONTH","5")
xpath=xpath.replace("DATE","30");
ele=driver.findElement(By.xpath(xpath));
ele.click()
```

You can use Firefox "Selenium IDE" to find the XPath, or install Firebug" then right-click and select "Inspect Element with Firebug". In the HTML tab right-click and select copy XPath.